# Install proxy server

Tags: proxy, server

Is it possible to install ccproxy on VM, and make it as a proxy server. I have tried to install ccproxy, but the proxy server doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran CCProxy on several VM's. You have to make sure you open the ports on the windows firewall for the incoming connections to work.
Please open the windows firewall settings and go to incoming and whatever port you chose for your http or SOCKS proxy make sure to unblock them. I think the default is 808 for http.

Answer (score -1):

Browsing though VMWare, I found this :

https://communities.vmware.com/message/1650585

Might help you I guess ?